# Google Scripts px to print unit

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Google Scripts to create a table in a GoogleDoc.

I am able to specify the width of a column with

```
 table.setColumnWidth(0, 100);
```

The first parameter refers to the column number whilst the second defines the column witdth in px.

The document that I am an generating is however for print. Therefore, I would prefer to use a print unit of measurement such as mm or inches.

Is it possible to do this?

If not, is there a formula to convert the value of my desired print unit to px?